# How to Get Bold Text with TikZ Decorations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, bold, text, decorations

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{mydecor/.style 2 args={decoration={text along path,
        text align={left indent=2em},
        text={|\Large|#2},
        },
      yshift=#1,
      decorate}}
      
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[brown!65!black] (-6,0) rectangle (6,9) (180:0.45cm) arc (180:360:0.45cm);
  \draw[line width=0.3cm,blue,fill=white,miter limit=1]
      (0,0.45) to[controls={+(150:2.25cm) and +(25:2.25cm)}] (-5.4,0.6) --
      (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}]
      (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6) --
      (5.4,0.6) to[controls={+(155:2.25cm) and +(30:2.25cm)}]
      (0,0.45) -- (0,9);
% Left page
  \path[mydecor={-7ex}{Bold text?}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
 
% Right page
  \path[mydecor={-7ex}{Bold text?}] (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

How may I make bold the displayed text? The usual methods don't seem to work, unless I'm not placing the commands in the proper place. I compile the code with `XeLaTeX.`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text is bold by placing `\bfseries` after `\Large` inside `|`...`|`. Thus `text={|\Large\bfseries|#2}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{mydecor/.style 2 args={decoration={text along path,
        text align={left indent=2em},
        text={|\Large\bfseries|#2},
        },
      yshift=#1,
      decorate}}
      
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[brown!65!black] (-6,0) rectangle (6,9) (180:0.45cm) arc (180:360:0.45cm);
  \draw[line width=0.3cm,blue,fill=white,miter limit=1]
      (0,0.45) to[controls={+(150:2.25cm) and +(25:2.25cm)}] (-5.4,0.6) --
      (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}]
      (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6) --
      (5.4,0.6) to[controls={+(155:2.25cm) and +(30:2.25cm)}]
      (0,0.45) -- (0,9);
% Left page
  \path[mydecor={-7ex}{Bold text?}] (-5.4,9.6) to[controls={+(25:2.25cm) and +(150:2.25cm)}] (0,9);
 
% Right page
  \path[mydecor={-7ex}{Bold text?}] (0,9) to[controls={+(30:2.25cm) and +(155:2.25cm)}] (5.4,9.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```